# Creating a variable to separate different data sets

Tags: regression

I am conducting analysis to determine what attracts FDI (foreign direct investment) flows into 3 different states for the period of 1996 - 2015. I have multiple independent variables for each of these states for the mentioned period. I have combined the 3 data sets together. I am intending to run one multiple linear regression for these 3 countries so therefore I need to create a variable that could separate the 3 data sets.

However, I do not know how to create a 'dataset' variable that would actually differentiate between these 3 data sets and how should I interpret its significance.

To provide more context, I am facing a similar problem as was posted here :[Combining multiple datasets vs combining regression models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235577/combining-multiple-datasets-vs-combining-regression-models/264960?noredirect=1#comment506959_264960)

One of the answers in this seem to answer my question by: "I suggest combining the datasets into one and fitting a single overall model. In this model I would include a "dataset" variable (i.e. a variable that differentiates between the datasets)"

However my problem is that, I do not know how to create such variable. I am using SPSS software.

Comment: Welcome to CV. On the whole, your question does not meet the most basic hurdles for posing questions on CV. These include discussing the steps you've taken in researching your query as well as the specifics of your confusion. Another issue concerns use of an acronym, i.e.., FDI. I understand that this refers to "foreign direct investment," but many other readers may not. That said, one approach (there's actually several) to creating a "dataset" variable would be to create a categorical or qualitative factor (like a grouping variable in ANOVA) with 3 levels, 1 per state.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have updated the question.

Comment: What you have proposed is a panel data or pooled cross section, time series model. There is an abundant literature on this class of models. In econometrics, your area of application, the canonical work has been done by Wooldridge in his book *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some kind of discriminant analysis can help? For example, LDA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis), QDA, etc. It gives variables and discriminant function for datasets.

Comment: Can you expand on this as at the moment it is hard to see how you think this is going to help the questioner? Perhaps set out the steps you would undertake to do LDA on his/her data-set.